# In Route.php line 817:Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: laravel

I cleared every instance of a closure from my web.php file but i'm still getting this error when I run php artisan route:cache.How do I fix this.

The format of the routes that I used are:

```
Route::get('/home',[

      'uses'=>'HomeController@index',

])->name('home');
```

and the other format is

```
Route::get('/profile',[

      'uses'=>'profileController@index',

]);
```

**Edit:** Formatted code

Comment: What about your `routes/api.php` file, if it exists?

Comment: Oh yes,it does exist and it contain's a closure.How do I go about this?

Comment: My problem started of when I hosted my website.Only the index route is found, and the other routes cannot be found on the server.

Comment: Same way you modified `routes/web.php` I would assume. Post the route definition if you would like help with that.

Comment: That's typically caused by `mod_rewrite` not being enabled/configured. Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: yes please,I wouldn't mind some help

Comment: Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Comment: Im using Apache

Comment: You'll need to create a UserController for API routes. Run `php artisan controller:create UserController --resource`. Then change the route to be: `Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController')`.

Comment: Ok I will do this.Will I need to configure any code as well in my .htaccess file as well?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, I believe Laravel comes with the .htaccess file preconfigurared for you.

Comment: Oh ok,thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way around this error its due to Route present in the  `routes > api.php` , just comment it out and files will be cached successfully.

```
// Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {

//     return $request->user();

// });
```